# aiohttp request.multipart() get nothing from browser uploading files

Tags: python, vue.js, multipartform-data, aiohttp

browser using vue element-ui el-upload component to upload file,and aiohttp as backend receive form data then save it.but aiohttp request.multipart() was always blank but request.post() will be ok.

**vue:**

```
   <el-upload class="image-uploader" 
        :data="dataObj" 
         drag 
         name="aaa"
        :multiple="false" 
        :show-file-list="false"
        :action="action"  -> upload url,passed from outer component
        :on-success="handleImageScucess">
      <i class="el-icon-upload"></i>
    </el-upload>

export default {
  name: 'singleImageUpload3',
  props: {
    value: String,
    action: String
  },
  methods: {
   handleImageScucess(file) {
      this.emitInput(file.files.file)
    },

  }
```

**aiohttp: not work**

```
 async def post_image(self, request):

        reader = await request.multipart()

        image = await reader.next()
        print (image.text())
        filename = image.filename
        print (filename)
        size = 0
        with open(os.path.join('', 'aaa.jpg'), 'wb') as f:
            while True:
                chunk = await image.read_chunk()

                print ("chunk", chunk)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                size += len(chunk)
                f.write(chunk)
        return await self.reply_ok([])
```

**aiohttp: work**

```
async def post_image(self, request):
        data = await request.post()
        print (data)
        mp3 = data['aaa']

        filename = mp3.filename

        mp3_file = data['aaa'].file

        content = mp3_file.read()
        with open('aaa.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(content)
        return await self.reply_ok([])
```

browser console:

[image]

bug or anything i missed ? please help me to solve it,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might have check the example at [aiohttp document about file upload server](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#file-uploads). But that snippet is ambiguous, and the document doesn't explain itself very well.

After digging around its source code for a while, I found that `request.multipart()` actually yields a `MultipartReader` instance, which processes `multipart/form-data` requests one field each time on calling of `.next()`, yielding another `BodyPartReader` instance.

In your not working code, `image = await reader.next()` that line actually reads out one entire field from the form data, which you can't be sure which field it actually is. It might be the `token` field, the `key` field, the `filename` field, the `aaa` field... or any of them. So in your not working example, that `post_image` coroutine function will only process one single field from your requesting data, and you cannot be very sure that it is the `aaa` file field.

Here's my code snippet,

```py
async def post_image(self, request):
    # Iterate through each field of MultipartReader
    async for field in (await request.multipart()):
        if field.name == 'token':
            # Do something about token
            token = (await field.read()).decode()
            pass

        if field.name == 'key':
            # Do something about key
            pass

        if field.name == 'filename':
            # Do something about filename
            pass

        if field.name == 'aaa':
            # Process any files you uploaded
            filename = field.filename
            # In your example, filename should be "2C80...jpg"

            # Deal with actual file data
            size = 0
            with open(os.path.join('', filename), 'wb') as fd:
                while True:
                    chunk = await field.read_chunk()
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    size += len(chunk)
                    fd.write(chunk)

    # Reply ok, all fields processed successfully
    return await self.reply_ok([])
```

And the snippet above can also deal with multiple files in single request with duplicate field name, or 'aaa' in your example. The `filename` in `Content-Disposition` header should be automatically filled in by the browser itself, so no need to worry about `filename`.

BTW, when dealing with file uploads in requests, `data = await request.post()` will eat up considerable amount of memory to load file data. So `request.post()` should be avoided when involving file uploads, use `request.multipart()` instead.

Comment: I need to add an `Authorization` header and an `image/jpg` file as multipart request and later recieve both seperately at `request handler`. Can you explain that case too.